# Git: Is commit content sent to network even after fatal error?

Tags: git, git-push

During an attempted push, is any of the substantive content of my commit (i.e., the code I was working on) sent over the network, if the push results in any of the following errors? (where '%s' is the remote repo)

1. fatal: repository '%s' not found
2. fatal: Authentication failed for '%s'
3. fatal: unable to access '%s'

Comment: Git operations are supposed to in general be atomic, meaning the repo should only record the operation if no errors occurred.  That being said, assuming a problem popped up halfway through, this does not mean that none of your data got sent over, only that it didn't end up in e.g. a broken commit.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you consider the "unable to access" error for instance, you would find it in [`http-push.c#static int remote_exists(const char *path)`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6d5b26420848ec3bc7eae46a7ffa54f20276249d/http-push.c#L1519-L1533)

It is called from [`http-push.c#cmd_main()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6d5b26420848ec3bc7eae46a7ffa54f20276249d/http-push.c#L1796-L1798) at a time where push is busy *getting* data from the remote repo, in order to determine the have/have not pack files, and know what to *send back*, [as illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39008227/6309).